# Regexp for floating number

Tags: javascript, regex

I found this regexp for validating floats. But I cant see how 2-1 will accepted. The below evaluates to true. I can't use parseFloat because I need to be able to accept "," instead of "." also. I wrote re2, same result though.

```
var re1 = new RegExp("^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$");
console.log(re1.test("2-1"));

var re2 = new RegExp("^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$");
console.log(re2.test("2-1"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you generate the regex using the constructor function, you have to to escape the backslash, i.e. `\` becomes `\\`:

```
var re1 = new RegExp("^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$");
```

Another option is to use the literal syntax which doesn't require escaping:

```
var re1 = /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes when you create a regex string, you even have to escape the backslash; this can of course be done with a backslash, so the final regex looks something like `"\\.*"`, etc.

Doing this, I was able to get the correct results, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/EMdPB/):

```
var re1 = new RegExp("^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$");
console.log(re1.test("2-1"));

var re2 = new RegExp("^([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)$");
console.log(re2.test("2-1"));

console.log(re1.test("2.1"));
console.log(re2.test("2.1"));​
```

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing a comma (",") with a period (".") and then using parseFloat?